# Windows10: Why is the Winamp application not minimized automatically when I click anywhere else on a different application?

Tags: windows-10, application-launch, winamp

since yesterday I have this problem.

The Winamp application is no longer minimized automatically when I click anywhere else on a different application. Basicaly, Winamp stays in the air, in the front of any other application I work, everytime. I must click the "minimize" winamp button to put it down, otherwise stays there.

What is the solution for this? Why is this happening suddenly?

Comment: In Winamp, open the Options menu, and make sure "Always On Top" is unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer : In Winamp, open the Options menu, and make sure that
"Always On Top" is unchecked.